# Running npm install with post install script installing a subdirectory app on github-actions inside docker container fails

Tags: github, npm, github-actions, npm-install, docker-container

I'm getting this error when I try to run `npm install` in github actions. I have a subfolder which has another project and on `postinstall` I run the `npm install` for that subfolder.
Here is the worflow.yml file

```
name: Install and cache dependencies
on:
  workflow_call:

jobs:
  install-and-cache-dependencies:    
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # Builder image it contains nodeJs + chromium to run the tests on the ui using puppeteer. We had to build our own because there is no official
    # image for this. Version 16.13.0 is the nodeJs version which is installed inside the package.
    container:
      image: houzy/frontend-builder:16.13.1
      env:
        NODE_OPTIONS: "--max_old_space_size=4096"
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Create hash key
        run: touch ${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}.hash-file

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install # npm run install:widgets is run as a post install script

      - name: Ivy post-install processing
        # This script goes through libraries and adjust them so that they work properly with the Ivy. It stores
        # results in node_modules, so it will change whenever some dependencies change.
        run: npm run postinstall-ivy
```

Here is the complete error from `Install dependencies` step

```
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated postinstall-build@5.0.3: postinstall-build's behavior is now built into npm! You should migrate off of postinstall-build and use the new `prepare` lifecycle script with npm 5.0.0 or greater.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.3.3: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm WARN deprecated @types/swiper@6.0.0: This is a stub types definition. swiper provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
npm WARN deprecated @types/express-winston@4.0.0: This is a stub types definition. express-winston provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
npm WARN deprecated sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
npm WARN deprecated @wessberg/ts-evaluator@0.0.27: this package has been renamed to ts-evaluator. Please install ts-evaluator instead

> angular-frontend@1.0.0 postinstall
> cd widgets && npm install

npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /__w/angular-frontend/angular-frontend/widgets/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/__w/angular-frontend/angular-frontend/widgets/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/__w/angular-frontend/angular-frontend/widgets/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/__w/angular-frontend/angular-frontend/widgets/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /github/home/.npm/_logs/2023-01-12T10_19_14_334Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code 243
npm ERR! path /__w/angular-frontend/angular-frontend
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c cd widgets && npm install

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /github/home/.npm/_logs/2023-01-12T10_19_14_398Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 243.
```

`Install Dependencies` step runs `npm install` and in my `package.json` I have a `postinstall` script

```
{
  "scripts": {
     "postinstall": "cd widgets && npm install"
  }
}
```

Seems the permissions error comes from the container image `houzy/frontend-builder:16.13.1`, cause removing the `container` part from workflow makes the pipeline work. I would like to understand what I should set in the `container` part from the `worflow` or in the `Dockerfile` for creating this `image` to make it work.
Here is the `Dockerfile` to create the image:

```
# Dockerfile used for replacing bitbucket pipeline start image

FROM node:16.13.0

RUN apt-get update; apt-get install -y gettext-base;
RUN echo 'deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/chrome.list
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN set -x && apt-get update && apt-get install -y xvfb google-chrome-stable
RUN wget -q -O /usr/bin/xvfb-chrome https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/docker-node-chrome-firefox/raw/ff180e2f16ea8639d4ca4a3abb0017ee23c2836c/scripts/xvfb-chrome
RUN ln -sf /usr/bin/xvfb-chrome /usr/bin/google-chrome
RUN chmod 755 /usr/bin/google-chrome
RUN curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip" && unzip awscliv2.zip && ./aws/install
RUN curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && python3 get-pip.py --user && ~/.local/bin/pip install --upgrade awsebcli
```

As a side note I use the same image in `bitbucket-pipelines` and there it works so maybe just the start container command is different on `github-actions` ?

Comment: Is this command `mkdir '/__w/angular-frontend/angular-frontend/widgets/node_modules'` coming from your code?

Comment: No, `npm install` does it because I have a `postinstall` script which does `cd widgets && npm install` which basically results in that error when `npm` it tries to create the directory `node_modules` inside the `widgets` directory

Comment: I managed to identify the problem it seems the problem is inside the container `houzy/frontend-builder:16.13.1` the scripts don't have permissions unfortunately I didn't investigate the proper fix because I could avoid this image entirely using the installed dependencies in `ubuntu-latest` from github-actions runner. I will also post the docker file to create that image.

Comment: Good to hear that. You might want to self-answer this question in case someone encounters it.